# Swift 4 SpriteKit detection of contacts

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am currently programming an application for iOS in swift 4, but running into problems while trying to detect two "SkSpritenodes" hitting each other – detect contacts.

At the first glance I have everything done set the bit masks etc. but it seems like I have not done it the right way.

Here is my code maybe you can help me.

I think it is a problem many others may have as well, maybe do to wrong bit masks?

```
 import SpriteKit
 import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
     let bananenkategorie: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
     let ananaskategorie: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
     let kirschekategorie: UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
     let traubekategorie: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
     let bombe1kategorie: UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
     let bomb2kategorie: UInt32 = 0x1 << 6
     let korbkategorie: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0

var korb = SKSpriteNode()
var timer: Timer!

func neuesobst(art: String, menge: Int, geschwindigkeit: TimeInterval){
    if art == "Banane"{
        let banane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Banane.png")

        banane.size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
        banane.color = UIColor.yellow
        var randomx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.width)))
        if randomx < Int(banane.size.width){randomx = randomx + Int(banane.size.width)}
        if randomx > Int(self.frame.size.width - banane.size.width){randomx = randomx - Int(banane.size.width)}
        banane.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomx), y: self.frame.size.height+banane.size.height)
        banane.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 60)
        banane.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bananenkategorie
        banane.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        banane.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = korbkategorie
        banane.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        banane.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

        self.addChild(banane)
        banane.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: -10, duration: geschwindigkeit))
     // adding one sprite, I ad all other sprites the same way.

 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    korb = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Korb.png")
    korb.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)
    korb.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = korbkategorie
    korb.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    korb.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =   bananenkategorie|ananaskategorie|traubekategorie|kirschekategorie|bomb2kategorie|bombe1kategorie
    korb.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 300, height: 200))
    korb.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)
    korb.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    korb.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.addChild(korb)

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 100)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.9, target: self,   selector: #selector(spawn), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
} // here is: the did move to view function. So I am checking the collision of the "Korb" node and the "Banane" node.

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    korb.alpha = 0 // just to test if anything works
}                      // but it doesn't it doesn't even go into this     function anytime even when you clearly see a collision between two sprites on screen
```

Comment: Solved it! Finally. Like I thought there was a problem with the bit masks.

Comment: For anyone who has the same problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miQ4YmPtFJE&t=417s&frags=pl%2Cwn.

Comment: Was the solution to remove the ‘?’ when you create the physics bodies?

Comment: the issue is the `SKPhysicsBody` is created AFTER the korb bit masks were set.  I recommend not using `?` ever until you get use to the fact that you should only use `?` when you expect nil to be a valid result

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    korb = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Korb.png")
    korb.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)
    korb.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = korbkategorie
    korb.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    korb.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =   bananenkategorie|ananaskategorie|traubekategorie|kirschekategorie|bomb2kategorie|bombe1kategorie
    korb.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 300, height: 200))
    korb.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)
    korb.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    korb.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.addChild(korb)

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 100)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.9, target: self,   selector: #selector(spawn), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
} // here is: the did move to view function. So I am checking the collision of the "Korb" node and the "Banane" node.
```

Specifically:

```
korb.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = korbkategorie
korb.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
korb.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =   bananenkategorie|ananaskategorie|traubekategorie|kirschekategorie|bomb2kategorie|bombe1kategorie
korb.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 300, height: 200))
```

You have:
nil
nil
nil
body

Which is not what you want.

Use `!` instead of `?` when dealing with optionals and let the program crash. 
This will help you debug your code a lot easier.

The only time you should place a `?`, is when you are expecting nil to be a valid value.